# use of unresolved identifier "class" with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode: 8.3.2
Project Name: Tracking

I write a `beaconManger.swift` with no error, and gonna to use it in `ViewController.swift`. Soon it pops the **error**:

> "use of unresolved identifier beaconManger".

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, beaconManagerDelegate {
    ...
    var beaconManager: beaconManager!
    ...

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        beaconManager = beaconManger()  //use of unresolved identifier beaconManger
        .......
}
```

Both class has set Target Membership to Tracking. 
Can anyone help me on it?

Comment: Class names should start with uppercase letters. Variable and method names start with lowercase. This avoids the confusion of `var beaconManager: beaconManager`

Comment: `beaconManger` or `beaconManager`? And you'd better not use the same name for class and property in Swift.

Comment: Well noted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Class have to start with a uppercase
like

```
class BeaconManager {

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, beaconManagerDelegate {
    ...
    var beaconManager: BeaconManager!
    ...

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        beaconManager = BeaconManger()  //use of unresolved identifier beaconManger
        .......
}
```